# Ajaxform getting the data before the submit is called

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajaxform

I am working with [AjaxForm plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form)

I want to alert the data what is being pushed to server.

```
<form class='frmAppList'>
    <input type='hidden' name='deviceid' value='<deviceId>'>
    <input type='hidden' name='operationtype' value='<Coming from server>'>
    <input type='hidden' name='type' value='command'>
    <button type="submit" class='btnAppsList button'>
         APPS LIST
    </button>
</form>
```

This is in loop in **jsp** so the **form** is generated more than once having **class** -> **frmAppList**.

I am using the class to apply **ajaxform** like this:

```
$('.frmAppList').ajaxForm({
   url : 'urltoserver',
   dataType : 'json',
   type : 'post',
   beforeSubmit : function() {
     return false;
     //something here that gives me the device id that is passed
     //since the form is not one I cant use id, also every form has **deviceid**
     //i need to get that deviceid so that i can pass it in **success** ajax call
     //at ***Label->(A)*** 
   },
   success : function(response) {
      if (response.status) {
        //***Label*** ->(A)
        //have to call other ajax call to take the data 
        //for that i need the device id that is going in this ajax call
      }
   },
   error : function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
      alert('error');
   },
   timeout :10000
});
```

How can I get that device Id,plz help me....
Thanks a ton.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From ajaxForm doc :

```
success
Callback function to be invoked after the form has been submitted. If a 'success' callback function is provided it is invoked after the response has been returned from the server. It is passed the following arguments:
1.) responseText or responseXML value (depending on the value of the dataType option).
2.) statusText
3.) xhr (or the jQuery-wrapped form element if using jQuery < 1.4)
4.) jQuery-wrapped form element (or undefined if using jQuery < 1.4)
Default value: null
```

The third and fourth argument are what you're looking for. Start there:

```
success : function(response,status,request,form) {
  console.log(request,form);
}
```

Comment: Ok I got it but how could I access deviceId, if I say `alert(form)`, it says **[object,object]**, and if I say `JSON.stringify(form)` it throws error as: 

Accessing selectionDirection on an input element that cannot have a selection.

Comment: this is why I wrote console.log, not alert. You need to use firebug or google chrome's developer console.
https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview

http://getfirebug.com/